# Macro issues in Excel365 with Smooth Scrolling

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, scrolling

I was asked on Stackoverflow to take my question here instead.

When creating an Excel file in Office365 including macros that increase and decrease value in a cell depending if you click up or down arrow causes issues when the sheet isn't perfectly aligned with the rows. This has been verified by Microsoft in case 34137940 as a bug - who suggested to ask the question here and reach out to a developer support team member. The problem is that no matter if I click up or down when a row is "visually splitted" the amount increases in the cell.

So what can I do to make this work as intended? I don't want to wait until Microsoft pushes an update. There has to be a solution for me to be able to disable smooth-scrolling somehow?

There is a temporary solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-is-now-smooth-scrolling-but-i-want-to-turn/d751c6f7-11a1-4106-be46-11ad5a5d2389) to solve this by running the below commands to revert to earlier update - but that is not an option in this case since newer features is used as well.

```
cd %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\
OfficeC2RClient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.14701.20262
```

I also tried disabling smooth scrolling in Windows 10 ([Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-smooth-scrolling-for-metro-apps-in/b77bad5c-2705-4c9a-aec4-42726161eb88)), following the below steps - with no success.

1. Navigate to **System Properties** by right clicking **Properties **from my computer.
2. Click on **Advanced** and click on **Performance settings**.
3. In **Visual Effects tab of Performance Options** window, click **Custom**. Then **deselect** the following items to **Disable** some unnecessary eye candy:
4. Uncheck **Smooth-scroll** list boxes.

### To recreate the problem follow these steps.

1. Under the tab **Development** click **Insert** and select **Spin button** under **Form control**
2. Right click the button and select **Format Control**
3. Under the tab **Control** click the arrown on the option **Cell link** and select a cell you want to increase/decrease the value in
4. Hit **OK**
5. Make a row in the sheet bigger and scroll until that row is split visually on screen.
6. Now, no matter if you click the up or down arrow, the value will increase

Comment: I still haven't found a solution about this problem, nor have I heard anything from Microsoft about it.